# Lock screen wallpaper option on ubuntu 20.04 LTS is not available?

Tags: lock-screen, 20.04, desktop-background

Lock screen wallpaper option on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is not available unlike in 18.04 LTS.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: This is by design. Curtain style login screen is no longer available. GNOME 3.36 uses blurred desktop wallpaper as the background of lock screen. [Example video](https://youtu.be/ae2D4aWTsXM?t=85) by GNOME.

Comment: @Kulfy I chose that metro st. image but still getting old purple color lockscreen after boot. I upgraded from 19.10 . Is there any solution ?

Comment: @xaif Is it before starting the user session? If no, consider asking a new question with details and screenshots. Comments are not intended for asking new questions.

Comment: @Kulfy Sorry, that's unacceptable because it *%$#s up my ultra-dark theme, preventing me from having a fully reverseable white/black background turning both into a solid gray which is TOO bright for dark mode!

Answer (score 9):

Ubuntu 20.04 uses the newest version of Gnome 3.36. This version has a new lock-screen now, it doesn't have separated screensaver and login window anymore but the same window for both. Also the new lock screen doesn't display any separated picture now - it blurs a wallpaper you have on your desktop (you can easily check it changing wallpapers and locking your screen). In other words, it's not a bug but absolutely normal behavior. I assume there is or there will be some possibility to change it, perhaps Dconf can help with that but I'm not sure since this is a pretty new feature.

Comment: https://blogs.gnome.org/shell-dev/2020/02/18/login-and-unlock-in-gnome-shell-3-36/ might explain the thinking behind.

Comment: so here's the problem... my background is solid white (or black, if I reverse video for ultra-dark mode), but this blurring turns my white color middle gray and my black color middle gray also, making my lock screen way too bright at night!

Answer (score 9):

You can have a lock screen wallpaper as you wish with this extension.

[Lock screen background](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1476/unlock-dialog-background/)

[image]

[image]

Comment: This extension works very well on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: ugh. again an extension that implying that maybe I need to install something for the browser (not sure, it doesn't seem to be able to tell me for sure) when i really just need a solid white/black background that isn't ruined by the stupid softening effect