# How to change wallpaper or background of lock screen in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, 20.04, login-screen, ubuntu-gnome

As any of the techniques used in earlier versions of Ubuntu is not working(editing .css file, running scripts, or through extensions etc). Are there any methods to change the background???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lock screen wallpaper option on ubuntu 20.04 LTS is not available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230714/lock-screen-wallpaper-option-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-is-not-available)

Comment: I tried the extension but it is not working as it gives some errors

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to ask Ubuntu.

### Answer to your question

Your lock screen is basically a blurred image, based on your main home screen. So without changing your home screen, it is impossible to change.

### Ways you might be able to do it

Now I have not tested this, but when I was using manjaro, I had a customized lock screen. I used this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_dYqisDIcC0) to customize it. I believe that this may override the basic home screen with your own choice. Others have also said that you can also try [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1476/unlock-dialog-background/) extension.

I believe this is new and intentional in GNOME 3.36.

Good luck!

Comment: I tried the extension but it is not working as it gives some errors and the video some how helped me but I want to stay in GDM3 only...