# Change Ubuntu 20.04 login theme

Tags: 20.04, themes, gdm

I want to use [Materia](https://github.com/nana-4/materia-theme) theme as my login screen (gdm) theme. I used [loginized](https://github.com/juhaku/loginized) app for changing the theme, I used it on arch and it worked well. But it is not working for ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Can you show exactly how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the file `/usr/share/themes/Materia/gnome-shell/README.md`.. please read the warnings first.. If you wish to proceed even after understanding the warnings in it..

follow the below steps to have a Materia theme for gdm login greeter..

**Please note that This is just one of the workaround.. there are different ways..**

Install the required package

```
sudo apt install libglib2.0-dev-bin
```

Backup the original theme first.

```
sudo cp -av /usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource{,~}
```

Change the Directory to Materia theme

```
cd /usr/share/themes/Materia/gnome-shell/
```

Create a copy of gnome-shell.css as gdm3.css

```
sudo cp gnome-shell.css gdm3.css
```

Edit the file `gnome-shell-theme.gresource.xml` to add the line `<file>gdm3.css</file>`

```
sudo -H gedit gnome-shell-theme.gresource.xml
```

Observe, I have add the line `<file>gdm3.css</file>` under this line `<file>gnome-shell.css</file>`

```
<file>extensions/workspaces-to-dock/workspaces-to-dock.css</file>
<file>gnome-shell.css</file>
<file>gdm3.css</file>
<file>icons/eye-not-looking-symbolic.svg</file>
<file>icons/eye-open-negative-filled-symbolic.svg</file>
```

Save the file & close.

Create the required "gresource" file replacing the original file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource`

```
sudo glib-compile-resources --target=/usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource gnome-shell-theme.gresource.xml
```

Ok, Manipulation is done. Now tell the gdm to use the above manipulated file for login screen with below command and choose the number related to file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource`.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config  gdm3-theme.gresource
```

Example:

```
admin@i7-4770:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config  gdm3-theme.gresource 
[sudo] password for admin: 
There are 2 choices for the alternative gdm3-theme.gresource (providing /usr/share/gnome-shell/gdm3-theme.gresource).

  Selection    Path                                                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource   15        auto mode
* 1            /usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource              10        manual mode
  2            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource   15        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
admin@i7-4770:~$
```

Reboot to see the changes..

[image]

[image]

Optinally you may change the background color or image or any part.

If something gnone wrong and not able to see the login screen.. follow the README.md file.

---

The above changes only the login screen theme to Materia.. for lock screen you need to configure it separately. Follow this link [How to customize Lock Screen theme in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1238438/739431) to understand the concept, Once understood, you may use this content for proper configuration.

```
{
    "parentMode": "user",
    "stylesheetName": "gnome-shell.css",
    "themeResourceName": "gnome-shell-theme.gresource",
    "debugFlags": ["backtrace-crashes-all"],
    "enabledExtensions": ["ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com", "ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com", "desktop-icons@csoriano"]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! You just saved my day.

Comment: I tried the lock screen one, but it didn't work for some reason. Anybody know if they've updated anything?

Comment: What is the output of `gnome-shell --version`

Comment: @UnKNOWn 3.38.2 on Ubuntu 20.10. The gdm theme worked but not lock screen.

Comment: 3.38 is different.. Use extension unlockDialog

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1230739/739431

Comment: Do you know anything about changing the actual theme of it though and not just the background?

Comment: Yes thats possible.. Can you raise a new question with full details?