# How to change lock screen and login screen theme to any other theme

Tags: 20.04, themes, gnome-shell, login-screen, gdm

I need help changing **the login screen theme as well as the lock screen theme to [Orchis](https://github.com/vinceliuice/Orchis-theme)**.
I tried:

- [How to customize Lock Screen theme in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1238438/739431)
- [Change Ubuntu 20.04 login theme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264465/change-ubuntu-20-04-login-theme)
- [How do I change login screen theme or background in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227070/how-do-i-change-login-screen-theme-or-background-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Nothing works and gdm crashes. Also I don't know where is the `gnome-shell-theme.gresource.xml` file. I usually download it from [here](https://raw%20.githubusercontent.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/master/data/gnome-shell-theme.gresource.xml) as mentioned in [here *(the github link is outdated in this page)*](https://titanwolf.org/Network/Articles/Article?AID=0890c33e-565a-4248-9883-ef4202239706)

For Files: [/usr/share/themes/Orchis-dark-compact](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PygDdg_eMqYHrArKEgylJNXaqpVa1P2Z?usp=sharing)